# Why can't I centre a div?

Tags: html, css

I cannot seem to centre the bottom div. (middle9).

The HTML and CSS appears to be the same as the above code.

I apologise in advance if it is obvious, but I just cannot see it.

http://www.garyhornephotography.com/str/index.html

```css
wrap9 { width: 900px; height: 300px; background-color:#F67E07; margin-top: 3px; text-align:center; }

#sub_left9 { float:left;width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#96CBF7; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:5px; }
#sub_right9 { float:right; width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#A2F685; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 5px; }
#sub_middle9 { display:inline-block; width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#A2F685; margin-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="wrap9">

<div id="sub_left9"> left 9</div>
<div id="sub_middle9"> middle 9 </div>
<div id="sub_right9"> right 9 </div>

</div><!--wrap9 -->
```

Answer (score 8):

you are missing the id selector `#` off the css for the `wrap9` - try this

```css
#wrap9 { width: 900px; height: 300px; background-color:#F67E07; margin-top: 3px; text-align:center; }

#sub_left9 { float:left;width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#96CBF7; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:5px; }
#sub_right9 { float:right; width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#A2F685; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 5px; }
#sub_middle9 { display:inline-block; width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#A2F685; margin-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="wrap9">

<div id="sub_left9"> left 9</div>
<div id="sub_middle9"> middle 9 </div>
<div id="sub_right9"> right 9 </div>

</div><!--wrap9 -->
```

Comment: thanks - an easy thing to miss. I might also suggest to @ghp1968 to investigate using Bootstrap or other framework to make the divs responsive. Giving the divs a class of col-md-4 for example will display them horizontally for wider viewports and will stack them vertically in smaller viewports. Will still need the css to control margins and paddings, but will allow a mobile friendly version. Just a thought. :)

Answer (score 3):

```css
wrap9 { width: 900px; height: 300px; background-color:#F67E07; margin-top: 3px; text-align:center; }

#sub_left9 { float:left;width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#96CBF7; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:5px; }
#sub_right9 { float:left; width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#A2F685; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 5px; }
#sub_middle9 { float:left; display:inline-block; width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#A2F685; margin-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="wrap9">

<div id="sub_left9"> left 9</div>
<div id="sub_middle9"> middle 9 </div>
<div id="sub_right9"> right 9 </div>

</div><!--wrap9 -->
```

Just float them all left. :D

Comment: open op snippet in full screen. I dont think floating left for all is what the op is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way (without `float`) :

```css
#wrap9 { width: 900px; height: 300px; background-color:#F67E07; text-align:center; margin: 3px auto 0 auto;}

#sub_left9 { display:inline-block; width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#96CBF7; margin-top: 10px; margin-left:5px; }
#sub_right9 { display:inline-block; width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#A2F685; margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 5px; }
#sub_middle9 { display:inline-block; width:280px; height: 200px; background-color:#A2F685; margin-top: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="wrap9">

<div id="sub_left9"> left 9</div>
<div id="sub_middle9"> middle 9 </div>
<div id="sub_right9"> right 9 </div>

</div><!--wrap9 -->
```

If your `divs` display with `inline-block`, they will follow of the same flow and they are centered with the property `texte-align:center` by `#wrap9`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already accomplished that in wrap 6 and wrap 7.
You didn't define anything for wrap 9.

I would just make that a class, so you can re-use code :) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#sub_right9 {
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; left: 0; right: 0; position: relative; float: none; 
}
```

[Floating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) takes an element out of the normal flow of the document, and there is no center float value. Hence, you'll want to replace your CSS with the above to tell the 'right 9' green block to align to the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `#wrap9` add it as follows

```css
wrap9 { width: 900px; height: 300px; background-color:#F67E07; margin-top: 3px; text-align:center; }
```

Comment: Thanks for all your comments... Very much appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I know it can be very frustrating to center the div since they don't have the align: "center" tag working anymore in HTML5. You can also try this to center align the whole webpage.

**This is the easiest way to center any div tag.**

Apply the following CSS to it.

```
#divInner {
    width: 50%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Obviously you can change the width as you wish. The key part is setting margin as "auto".

If you want to control your margin on the left and right, replace the above "margin" property with the following.

```
margin-left: 0 auto;
margin-right: 0 auto;
```